# BeaufitulSoup Remove br in table and add full link

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am finally getting closer to extract a table from a specific website but my problem is that I cannot seem to figure out how to

1. Display the full link to the download file
2. remove the br in certain rows

the html code as follows

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
<tr class="bg">
<td><strong>Reference</strong></td>
<td stytle="width:100px"><strong>Description</strong></td>
<td><strong>Download Documents</strong></td>
<td stytle="width:50px"><strong>Closing Date</strong></td>
<td stytle="width:50px"><strong>Contact Details</strong></td>
<td><strong>Briefing</strong></td>
<!--<td><strong>PUBLISHED</strong></td>-->
</tr>
<tr>
<td>123456</td>
<td>text 123</td>
<td><a href="/downloads/linktofile.zip" target="_blank">Documents click here </a></td>
<td>2 weeks</td>
<td>me<br />
  you</td>
<td>next week</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>123456</td>
<td>text 123</td>
<td><a href="/downloads/linktofile.zip" target="_blank">Documents click here </a></td>
<td>2 weeks</td>
<td>me<br />
  you</td>
<td>next week</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>123456</td>
<td>text 123</td>
<td><a href="/downloads/downloads/linktofile.zip" target="_blank">Documents click here </a></td>
<td>2 weeks</td>
<td>me<br />
  you</td><td>next week</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>123456</td>
<td>text 123</td>
<td><a href="/downloads/linktofile.zip" target="_blank">Documents click here </a></td>
<td>2 weeks</td>
<td>me<br />
  you</td><td>next week</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>123456</td>
<td>text 123</td>
<td><a href="/downloads/downloads/linktofile.zip" target="_blank">Documents click here </a></td>
<td>2 weeks</td>
<td>me</td>
<td>next week</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>123456</td>
<td>text 123</td>
<td><a href="/downloads/linktofile.zip" target="_blank">Documents click here </a></td>
<td>2 weeks</td>
<td>me</td>
<td>next week</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I want to achieve that the **br** in the contact details will be removed and that the full link instead of "documents click here" is displayed.

Please be advised that this is an example table - rebuilt from the original project.

My python code works fine, just that it adds the content after 
 into a new link and the entire output.csv is mixed up.

## !/usr/bin/env python

## -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

```
import csv
import requests
import os
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from bs4 import Tag 

testwebsite = 'https://example.com'

uClient = uReq(testwebsite)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

testwebsitetendersaved=""
#Table is very ugly formated in a span tag and tables within tables
testwebsite_container = page_soup.find("span", id="MainContent2_ctl00_lblContent").findAll("table")[1]

for record in testwebsite_container.findAll('tr'):
    testwebsitetender=""
    for data in record.findAll('td'):
        testwebsitetender=testwebsitetender+","+data.text
    testwebsitetendersaved = testwebsitetendersaved + "\n" + testwebsitetender[1:]
    

header="Tender Number, Description, Documents Link, Closing Date, Contact Details, Briefing"+"\n"
file = open(os.path.expanduser("output.csv"), "wb")
file.write(bytes(header, encoding="ascii",errors='ignore'))
file.write(bytes(testwebsitetendersaved, encoding="ascii",errors='ignore'))

print(testwebsitetendersaved)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is what you want.

```
testwebsitetendersaved=""
#Table is very ugly formated in a span tag and tables within tables
testwebsite_container = page_soup.find("span", id="MainContent2_ctl00_lblContent").findAll("table")[1]

header="Tender Number, Description, Documents Link, Closing Date, Contact Details, Briefing"+"\n"
file = open(os.path.expanduser("output.csv"), "wb")
file.write(bytes(header, encoding="ascii",errors='ignore'))

skiptrcnt=1 # skip first tr block
for i,record in enumerate(testwebsite_container.findAll('tr')):
    if skiptrcnt>i:
        continue
    testwebsitetender=""
    tnum = record('td')[0].text
    desc = record('td')[1].text
    doclink = record('td')[2].text
    alink = record('td')[2].find("a")
    if alink :
        doclinkurl=testwebsite+alink['href']
    closingdate = record('td')[3].text
    detail = record('td')[4].text
    detail = detail.replace('\n', '')
    brief = record('td')[5].text
    brief = brief.replace('\n', '')
    print(tnum, desc, doclink, doclinkurl, closingdate, detail, brief)
    testwebsitetendersaved="{},{},{},{},{},{}\n".format(tnum, desc, doclink, doclinkurl, closingdate, detail, brief)
    file.write(bytes(testwebsitetendersaved, encoding="ascii",errors='ignore'))
file.close()
```

my output is

```
123456 text 123 Documents click here  https://example.com/downloads/linktofile.zip 2 weeks me  you next week
123456 text 123 Documents click here  https://example.com/downloads/linktofile.zip 2 weeks me  you next week
123456 text 123 Documents click here  https://example.com/downloads/downloads/linktofile.zip 2 weeks me  you next week
123456 text 123 Documents click here  https://example.com/downloads/linktofile.zip 2 weeks me  you next week
123456 text 123 Documents click here  https://example.com/downloads/downloads/linktofile.zip 2 weeks me next week
123456 text 123 Documents click here  https://example.com/downloads/linktofile.zip 2 weeks me next week
```

Comment: It displays the full link, thats perfect but for some reason the text after br tags are being moved into the next cell and sort of messes up the table again. Is it possible to remove the "documents click here" and replace it with the actual link?

Comment: Accepted your answer albeit it is not complete. Maybe you will reply to my question above

Comment: in assigning testwebsitetendersaved, chane doclink to doclinkurl. but already wrote. and detail carriage return problem, i’m not sure but try replace ‘\r’ to empty again. if it doesnot work, print detail and check.